# Is member declaration `decltype(name) name;` permitted in local struct where the first name refers to the enclosing scope?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Example:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    struct X
    {
        decltype(a) a;
    };
    return 0;
}
```

The `decltype(a)` refers to the local `a` in `main`, while the member it declares shares the same name.

[Clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/V8GwNp0y8Z6cKTsD) compiles w/o any problem, so does MSVC14.

[G++](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/V8GwNp0y8Z6cKTsD) complains on it, adding `-fpermissive` makes it pass though

```
prog.cc:6:21: error: declaration of 'int main()::X::a' [-fpermissive]
         decltype(a) a;
                     ^
prog.cc:3:9: error: changes meaning of 'a' from 'int a' [-fpermissive]
     int a = 0;
```

Which behavior is standard-conformant?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: this is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb ouch, is there a rationale for that?

Comment: @BЈовић Instead of a simple type like the `int` in this example, think of a situation where it's a very complicated type, possibly several levels of nested templates, it's not something one wants to write again. Also, what if the outer `a` was declared using `auto`?

Comment: @MattMcNabb prolly because it's confusing.. if it would be something that you want to define out of class the `decltype(a)` would suddenly refer to the data member. That's not a good thing.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb sorry, I mean is there a reason that no diagnostic is required - is this hard to detect as a compiler?

Comment: @MattMcNabb I guess you'd need to keep track of the decl referred to by the name during the initial parse, then check that against the decl referred to in the completed scope for *every* member. That seems like a lot of work for something which will be encountered very infrequently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this violates [basic.scope.class]/1 (N3337):

> The following rules describe the scope of names declared in classes.
>
> 1) [...]
>
> 2) A name `N` used in a class `S` shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of `S`. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

Since `decltype(a)` refers to the declaration in the enclosing scope before the member variable is declared, but refers to the member when "re-evaluated in the completed scope of" `X`, the program is ill-formed. No diagnostic is required, but GCC provides one anyway (although it's fairly arcane). The behaviour of all three compilers is valid.